# Check Progress of manual graphics fill

Tags: android, algorithm, graphics, coronasdk

I am working on a tattoo drawing game for mobile. There is a part in which player have to draw fill on the tattoo by finger. There I have to place a progress bar which will display how much area has been filled by players color. How can I trace the progress? There are almost 25 tattoos where this progress bar will work. So I need a generic technique.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some source code I wrote up that might help you:

```
local endPoint, startPoint
local lines, line, lx, ly, sx, sy = {}
local points = {}
r,g,b = 255,0,0
lineWidth = 10
local drawPacket

local odd = true

local function draw(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        startPoint = display.newCircle(0,0,lineWidth/2)
        startPoint.x, startPoint.y = event.x, event.y
        startPoint:setFillColor(r,g,b) 

        if startPoint.x <350 or startPoint.x > 700 then
            director:changeScene("fail")
        end

        endPoint = display.newCircle(-100,0,lineWidth/2) 
        endPoint:setFillColor(r,g,b)

        lineGroup:insert(startPoint)
        lineGroup:insert(endPoint)
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        if not line then
            print "I am now drawing the line"

            line = display.newLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, event.x, event.y)
            lines[ #lines + 1 ] = line
            line.width = lineWidth
            line:setColor(r,g,b)

            lx,ly = startPoint.x , startPoint.y
            sx,sy = event.x, event.y

            lineGroup:insert(line)
        else
            if math.sqrt((lx-event.x)^2+(ly-event.y)^2) > 2 then
                --print "I am now appending the line"
                line:append( event.x, event.y)
                lx, ly = event.x, event.y

            end
            endPoint.x = event.x
            endPoint.y = event.y
            if odd then

                points[#points+1] = event.x
                points[#points+1] = event.y

            end
            odd = not odd
        end
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        if win == true then
            if endPoint.x <350 or endPoint.x > 700 then
                director:changeScene("fail")
            else
                director:changeScene("scene11")
            end
        else
            director:changeScene("fail")
        end


        line = nil
        endPoint.x, endPoint.y = event.x, event.y
        print "I have ended my touch, sending data"
        points = {}
    end
end


background:addEventListener("touch", draw)
```

Make sure to replace "background" with your image that you want the user to "tattoo". Good luck with your project.